# Existence of a linear [13,6,5] code

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, upper-lower-bounds, coding-theory

I am trying to show that a code with length 13, dimension 6 and minimal distance 5 over $\mathbb{F}_q$ does not exist. I am confused though, doesn't this depend on $q$? I am also asked to show that such a code would satisfy the Hamming bound and Singleton bound but the Hamming bound also depends on $q$ right? Is there a way to show this directly?

Comment: see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2732046/generator-matrix-for-linear-8-5-3-code?

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This post seems to suggest $q=2$ which is part of my question. Is my problem well formulated or not?

Comment: I was referring to the comment on the second answer. See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2759684/439353. Further $q=2$ needs to be assumed in my opinion (as you point out).

Comment: Thanks for your comments! Yeah the Singleton bound works without a problem, but I was more referring to the Hamming bound which I was not super sure worked without explicitly knowing $q$ itself. I will just assume $q=2$, but it's weird because my prof usually says it's a binary code when $q=2$.

Comment: Yes, since now I know $q=2$ it works right? My question was more regarding whether this was true for any $q$, and if so, how should I go about proving it. But I will just assume my prof meant $q=2$ since this is more plausible.

Comment: @Saegusa The full text of the question probably says "binary $[13,6,5]$ code" or includes some other detail that suggests the assumption that $q=2$.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers The statement I have given is exactly what appeared on my assignment sheet. I cleared it up with the TA though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question must have been meant for binary codes only, i.e. $q=2$.
For $q\in\{3,4,5,7,8,9\}$, the database [codetables.de](http://codetables.de) gives the existence of a $[13,6,5]_q$-code. And for $q \geq 11$, there is always a $[q+1,6,q-4]_q$ MDS-Code (a Reed-Solomon code), which implies the existence of a $[13,6,5]_q$-code.

So assume that there is a $[13,6,5]$ **binary** linear code. Then the residual in a minimum weight codeword has the parameters $[13-5,6-1,>=\lceil 5/2\rceil] = [8,5,\geq 3]$, which cannot exist by Hamming bound. Contradiction.